# iTunes Connect reports

Tags: app-store-connect

I have a few questions:

1. Do the “Sales and Trends report” provides info about in-app purchase and organic traffic?
2. How can I upload the data from “Sales and Trends report”?

I’ve heard about method through using java classes?

Answer (score 1):

1. The reports you can download from the Sales & Trends section of iTunes Connect do give you aggregate transactional information about in-app purchases but not about organic traffic. Apple doesn't expose that at all.
2. Do you mean export? If so you'll want to look into the Auto Ingest tool. It's not an API but it will allow you to access your last 30 daily reports programatically.

Alternatively, you can use a service like [appFigures](http://appfigures.com) which syncs with iTunes Connect automatically and provides a very simple API to access sales data and much more.

*Full disclosure, I'm on the appFigures team*

Answer (score 0):

I will be happy to answer those questions.

**Question 1)** Sales And Trends show you just the money made (so yes to the In-App Purchases), but not the organic traffic. There is just some information that Apple likes to keep a secret, but we don't know why.

**Question 2)** Import means you put information into that section. You can't do that, but you can export the information, which means you get the information and download it.[image: The export button is in the black box.]

This is what "Sales and Trends" should look like, but there should be more information. I blocked out that information by slightly edited it. I put the download button in the black box. Then, you can choose the format you download it.

I hope this helped you get your answers!